# tex4ht: including section/subsection number in toc link

Tags: table-of-contents, tex4ht, links

I'm producing a document using `tex4ht`, and I would like to have the section and subsection numbers within the links in the TOCs, both main and mini.

For the main TOC, the following strategy works:

```
\def\tocsection#1#2#3{%
    % configure the link to put the secion number (contained in #1) 
    % within the toc link
    \Configure{TocLink}{\Link{##2}{##3}#1 ##4\EndLink}
    % then, when we output the section title, we don't 
    % want the section number again
    \HCode{<h2 class="sectionToc">}#2\HCode{</h2>}} % section
```

as demonstrated in the following screenshot:

[image]

### The problem

The problem is that, when I adapt this for the per-section/per-subsection tocs using the method below, the per-section/subsection 'cutting' of the tocs isn't obeyed, and I receive inaccurate minitocs:

[image]

Here is a minimal working example that demonstrates the problem:

### `cmh.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{My section}
My section text
\subsection{first subsection}
\subsection{second subsection}

\section{Another section}
\subsection{a third subsection}
\subsection{a fourth subsection}

\section{Final section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsection{subsection}
\end{document}
```

### `cmh.cfg`

```
\usepackage{cmh}
\Preamble{html5,5,next,-css,NoFonts}

% section
\def\tocsection#1#2#3{%
    % configure the link to put the secion number (contained in #1) 
    % within the toc link
    \Configure{TocLink}{\Link{##2}{##3}#1 ##4\EndLink}
    % then, when we output the section title, we don't 
    % want the section number again
    \HCode{<h2 class="sectionToc">}#2\HCode{</h2>}} % section

% subsection
\def\tocsubsection#1#2#3{%
    % as above
    \Configure{TocLink}{\Link{##2}{##3}#1 ##4\EndLink}
    \HCode{<h3 class="subsectionToc">}#2\HCode{</h3>}}      % subsection

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

### `cmh.4ht`

```
\Configure{TocAt*}
   {%
    \let\sv:atoc\a:tableofcontents
    \let\sv:btoc\b:tableofcontents
    \let\sv:ctoc\c:tableofcontents
    \let\sv:dtoc\d:tableofcontents
    \let\sv:etoc\e:tableofcontents
    \Configure{tableofcontents}
       {%
        \def\tocsubsection####1####2####3{%
            % configure the toclink so that the number is within the link
            \Configure{TocLink}{\Link{########2}{########3}####1 ########4\EndLink}
            \HCode{<h3 class="subsectionToc">}####2\HCode{</h3>}}%
       \IgnorePar\EndP\HCode{<h2>List of links for this section</h2><div class="\sec:typ TOCS">}\IgnorePar%
       }
       {}
       {\IgnorePar\HCode{</div>}\ShowPar\:CheckOption{7}}
       {\HCode{<br />}}
       {}%
    \ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP
   }
   {%
    \let\a:tableofcontents\sv:atoc
    \let\b:tableofcontents\sv:btoc
    \let\c:tableofcontents\sv:ctoc
    \let\d:tableofcontents\sv:dtoc
    \let\e:tableofcontents\sv:etoc
    \par\ShowPar}
\endinput
```

### `cmh.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{cmh}
\endinput
```

I'm compiling the files using the following command:

```
make4ht -u -f html5 -c cmh.cfg cmh.tex
```

### The question

How can I change the code above so that I can receive the Section/Subsection numbers within the TOC links, and maintain accurate per-section/per-subsection TOCs?

Comment: For reference, adding `\TocAt*{chapter,likechapter,section,likesection,subsection,likesubsection,subsubsection,likesubsubsection}` before `\begin{document}` in `cmh.cfg` means that you can remove all of the `\def\toc...` stuff from the `.4ht` file and achieve the same result with more reliable minitocs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redefinition of `\tocsubsection` erases the code that prints only subsections for the current sections. You need to test the `\TocCount` and `\TitleCount` counters to include only relevant subsections:

```
\Configure{TocAt*}
   {%
    \let\sv:atoc\a:tableofcontents
    \let\sv:btoc\b:tableofcontents
    \let\sv:ctoc\c:tableofcontents
    \let\sv:dtoc\d:tableofcontents
    \let\sv:etoc\e:tableofcontents
    \Configure{tableofcontents}
       {%
        \def\tocsubsection####1####2####3{%
            % configure the toclink so that the number is within the link
            \Configure{TocLink}{\Link{########2}{########3}####1 ########4\EndLink}
            \ifnum\TitleCount<\TocCount\HCode{<h3 class="subsectionToc">}####2\HCode{</h3>}\fi}%
       \IgnorePar\EndP\HCode{<h2>List of links for this section</h2><div class="\sec:typ TOCS">}\IgnorePar%
       }
       {}
       {\IgnorePar\HCode{</div>}\ShowPar\:CheckOption{7}}
       {\HCode{<br />}}
       {}%
    \ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP
   }
   {%
    \let\a:tableofcontents\sv:atoc
    \let\b:tableofcontents\sv:btoc
    \let\c:tableofcontents\sv:ctoc
    \let\d:tableofcontents\sv:dtoc
    \let\e:tableofcontents\sv:etoc
    \par\ShowPar}
\endinput
```

The relevant code is this:

```
\ifnum\TitleCount<\TocCount\HCode{<h3 class="subsectionToc">}####2\HCode{</h3>}\fi}%
```

I would also change the `\Preamble` command in the `cfg` file, as the `html5` option on the first place causes output to be non-well formed XML and thus causes issues with `make4ht` DOM filters. The better value would be something like this:

```
 \Preamble{xhtml,5,next,-css,NoFonts}
```

`HTML5` is used by `make4ht` by default, so you don't need to specify it.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! As always, tremendously helpful, thanks for your additional advice as well, it is very much appreciated

Comment: @cmhughes always happy to help :)

Comment: @cmhughes oh, thank you :)

Comment: You're very welcome :) and thank *you* for all of your support and work on make4ht and tex4ht